# Class template argument deduction before C++17

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

I was reading standard library documentation and found out that there were some functions like make_tuple. As far as I can see, these functions serve only one purpose: to construct class instance using automatic template argument deduction. Since CTAD was not available before C++17, associated make-functions had to be called. This gap was filled only in C++17. Now I wonder, why it couldn't be implemented earlier "the same way" as function template argument deduction? There should be an example that leads to ambiguity that cannot be resolved before C++17, I guess. Can someone confirm it? What is the difference between functions and classes in that regard? Thank you!

Comment: Why what couldn't be implemented earlier the same way?

Comment: Class template argument deduction for constructors.

Comment: Do you understand how the standardization process works? From an idea's conception until it is part of the working draft? (It's not irrelevant, bear with me)

Comment: I think this is a pretty reasonable question... "Why can we deduce function templte arguments but not class template arguments?" - If there's an obvious answer (beyond "the standard says so") or problem then it would be interesting to learn about.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I am not sure, if truly do. Just trying to understand, is there some implementation difficulties that I should be aware of, or it is the part of long iterative standardization process.

Comment: look at boost, many things have been implemented there before they made it into the c++ standard, because it was possible long time before the feature was standardized

Comment: Roughly speaking, for an idea to make it into the standard, someone has to come up with it, write a proposal/paper, accept and apply peer review, and also present and defend their feature in front of the committee, before voting is done on the paper (and that may even take you back to modifying the paper and presenting again). Many features take a *loooooong* time to germinate on account of it, even if someone thought of them years before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, standardization of a feature takes a long time.
If you wish to know in detail about it, you can check out  the section on [Standardization](https://isocpp.org/std) from https://isocpp.org, particularly ["The life of an ISO proposal: From “cool idea” to “international standard”"](https://isocpp.org/std/the-life-of-an-iso-proposal).

The paper that eventually made [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) possible in C++17 is titled [Template Tidbits](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3405.html) and was first published on 2012-09-22.

It underwent many revisions and the paper ["Template argument deduction for class templates"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html), which is the sixth revision of the paper was published on 2016-06-24.

So it took about five years for CTAD to go from “cool idea” to “international standard”.

Also as @StoryTeller notes, the idea itself has been around for a much longer time and is presented in the paper [Argument Deduction for Constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2332.pdf) which was published in 2007.

Comment: Is CTAD significantly harder than FTAD in some underlying way (say, name resolution)? Or were there mainly e.g. compatibility challenges for the standardization?

Comment: It's even older than 2012. Template tidbits references [n2332](https://wg21.link/n2332), the idea has been around since at least 2007!

Comment: @StoryTeller: Updated the answer with your input.